# Change of Integration Domains after Tonelli in Higher Dimensional Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, change-of-variable, fubini-tonelli-theorems

This might be considered as too general of a question but it has been bugging me for quite a while now: How does one change integration domains after using the Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem? Especially in higher dimensions when things are not "drawable"? Are there any algebraic ways or systematic ways to figure out the integration domains? Here I give one example of such situation just to illustrate what I meant:

[image]

To me, it is not immediately clear how we changed the integration domain like such. It makes sense somewhat that we have $\| \mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{y}' \| \leq x_N$ as $\mathbf{y}' \in B_{N-1}(\mathbf{x}', x_N)$, but how exactly would one start to think of such change of integration domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonelli's theorem only works when the domains of integration on each integral are constant. Use indicator functions to convert any seemingly non-constant domains of integration into constant ones. In your problem, you can convert $B_{N - 1}(x', x_N)$ into the whole space and multiply the integrand by
$I(y' \in B_{N - 1}(x', x_N))$. Now you apply Tonelli/Fubini to interchange integrals.